# Regex matches in C# but not in java

Tags: c#, java, regex

I have the following regex (long, I know):

```
(?-mix:((?-mix:(?-mix:\{\%).*?(?-mix:\%\})|(?-mix:\{\{).*?(?-mix:\}\}?))
|(?-mix:\{\{|\{\%)))
```

that I'm using to split a string. It matches correctly in C#, but when I moved the code to Java, it doesn't match. Is there any particular feature of this regex that is C#-only?

The source is produced as:

```
String source = Pattern.quote("{% assign foo = values %}.{{ foo[0] }}.");
```

While in C# it's:

```
string source = @"{% assign foo = values %}.{{ foo[0] }}.";
```

The C# version is like this:

```
string[] split = Regex.split(source, regex);
```

In Java I tried both:

```
String[] split = source.split(regex);
```

and also

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
String[] split = p.split(source);
```

Comment: Incorrect string escaping perhaps?!

Comment: Can you give a string that your expression should match?

Comment: There's nothing obviously broken in it. Could the problem be with the Java code that's using it? For example, people used to regexes in other languages will often use `matches` in Java when `find` is what's wanted. If you post a code-snippet, it might help. (By the way, why are you using so many instances of `(?-mix:...)`? You're not using `^`, `$`, letters, whitespace, or `#`, and even if you were, you'd only need one instance of that for the whole regex.)

Comment: O.K., your Java snippets look fine, also. Hmm . . . what does `source` look like? And, I assume that the regex that you posted is what you get from `System.out.println(regex);` (or the equivalent)?

Comment: You should see if you can narrow the problem down to a part of the regex by stripping a little bit at a time.  You should also confirm that the string you are searching is truly the same in both languages (and that for instance there wasn't some charset screw-up or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample program with your code: http://ideone.com/hk3uy

There is a major difference here between Java and other languages: Java does not add captured groups as tokens in the result array ([example](http://ideone.com/PcbHn)). That means that all delimiters are removed from result, though they would be included in .Net.
The only alternative I know is not to use `split`, but getting a list of matches and splitting manually.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize that .Net includes captured groups, but you're right: "If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx). But this isn't "Java" vs. "other languages"; Java's approach is more common in my experience, though .Net's isn't unique, either. (Python does it like .Net.)

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the problem.

Comment: @ruakh - That's fair. I don't deal with too many languages, but the delimiters are usually included, or at least optionally included (like in PHP's `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag).

Comment: By the way, in many cases a .Net-split-pattern-with-capture-groups could be converted to a Java-split-pattern-with-zero-width-lookahead-and-look-behind assertions. For example, C#'s `Regex.Split("123-456", "(-)")` is equivalent to Java's `Pattern.compile("(?=-)|(?<=-)").split("123-456")`. But in this case I don't think it's feasible to cram such a complex split-pattern into a zero-width lookbehind assertion . . .

Comment: @ruakh - That's a good point. Actually, I didn't pay too much attention to the actual pattern (it looked too auto-generated, and I've seen you already gave a better alternative, so I just voted on that) - but you are right. Very often the same result can be achieved in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with how you're defining `source`. On my system, this:

```
String source = Pattern.quote("{% assign foo = values %}.{{ foo[0] }}.");
```

is equivalent to this:

```
String source = "\\Q{% assign foo = values %}.{{ foo[0] }}.\\E";
```

(that is, it adds a stray `\Q` and `\E`), but the way the method is defined, your Java implementation could treat it as equivalent to this:

```
String source = "\\{% assign foo = values %\\}\\.\\{\\{ foo\\[0\\] \\}\\}\\.";
```

(that is, inserting lots of backslashes).

Your regex itself seems fine. This program:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?-mix:((?-mix:(?-mix:\\{\\%).*?(?-mix:\\%\\})|(?-mix:\\{\\{).*?(?-mix:\\}\\}?))|(?-mix:\\{\\{|\\{\\%)))");
    for(final String s : p.split("a{%b%}c{{d}}e{%f%}g{{h}}i{{j{%k"))
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

prints

```
a
c
e
g
i
j
k
```

that is, it successfully treats `{%b%}`, `{{d}}`, `{%f%}`, `{{h}}`, `{{`, and `{%` as split-points, with all the non-greediness you'd expect. But tor the record, it also works if I strip `p` down to just

```
Pattern.compile("\\{%.*?%\\}|\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}?|\\{\\{|\\{%");
```

;-)

Comment: Yes that line was added artificially. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was in fact that java does not include the separators in the result of the split.

Answer (score 0):

use `\\{` instead of `\{` and for other symbols too

Comment: Actually this is not the hard-coded string, but the product of a String.format() operation. It is already escaped.